# Kitchen Outlets dead

Tags: electrical, kitchens

I have 5 outlets in my kitchen. 3 are out. I reset the main breaker. Still no luck for the 3. Do I need to call an electrician?

Comment: There are 2 Gfci's in the kitchen. 1 will reset, on an outlet that functions. One, i push the test and there is nothing.

Comment: Are the dead outlets on the same circuit or different circuits?

Comment: "One, i push the test and there is nothing."  What if  you push "reset"?

Answer (score 1):

*As stated by OP in a [comment](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/106413/kitchen-outlets-dead#comment160482_106414):*

I feel kinda stupid. the breaker on the panel had turned red. reset and they all WORK!!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Look around for a GFCI receptacle that needs resetting.

It's possible for it to be not in the kitchen.

Comment: If a newer home the GFCI could be in the pantry, or dining area. The main breaker controls the entire home there should be 2 separate 20 amp breakers or if a multi wire branch circuit 1 20 amp double pole breaker feeding the kitchen. Possibly with an older home they could be 15 amp. The panel should have them listed turn them off and back on if no GFCI is found.

Comment: I feel kinda stupid. the breaker on the panel had turned red. reset and they all WORK!!! Thank you

Comment: Happens to all of us!